# XPages - querysavedocument event

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm working with the XPages querysavedocument event for the first time and am trying to stop the XPage from being saved. I've tried

```
return false;
```

but this does not stop the document from being saved. What is the correct syntax to stop the XPage from being saved?

The code which saves the document is:

```
<xp:this.action>
<xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
</xp:this.action>
```

This is the same as in Knut's answer below. The code which I have in the querySaveDocument is

```js
var choice:boolean = false;

for (var k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
    choice = false;
    sectionname = "C1B"+k;
    for (var n = 1; n < 7; n++) {
        fieldname = "C1B"+k+"_R"+n;

        if (getComponent(fieldname).getValue() != ""){
            choice = true; 
            break;};
    }

    if (choice == false){
        viewScope.put("EmptyRadioField",sectionname);
        var comp = getComponent("RadioButtonValidationDialog");
        comp.show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The dialog box is shown correctly when choice == false but the XPage is saved nonetheless.

I have solved my problem by moving the validation to csjs:

```js
for (var k = 1; k < 7; k++) {

choice = false;
sectionname = "C1B"+k;

for (var n = 1; n < 7; n++) {
fieldname = "C1B"+k+"_R"+n;

var id = "view:_id1:_id2:_id3:"+fieldname;
fieldvalue = dijit.byId(id).getValue();

if (fieldvalue != false){
choice = true; 
break;};

}

if (choice == false){

sectionid = "view:_id1:_id2:_id3:lbl"+sectionname;
sectionvalue = dojo.byId(sectionid).innerHTML;
alert("Please enter a value for " + sectionvalue);
return false;

}
}
```

This works well, despite a lot of trying I just couldn't get it working in SSJS.

Comment: So you are looking for XPages equivalent of `Continue = False` in LotusScript?

Comment: yes, that is what I want

Comment: Did you put the `}` in `break` line on purpose? -I guess, last if should be **inside** of both `for` loops?

Comment: Yes, the code is as I want it. Once an empty field is found, the dialog is displayed.  This however seems to happen after the document has already been saved. The choice == false condition is triggered outside the n loop but inside the k loop.

Comment: If I replace the above code with simply "return = false;", the document is nonetheless saved.

Comment: Ok, then it is not about the code above. Do you have somewhere else a `document1.save()` or similar code? Maybe in a embedded custom control?

Answer (score 1):

`return false;` is right.

Maybe, the event `querySaveDocument` **does not get executed** at all. That happens e.g. if you save the document in SSJS with `document1.save()`.

You have to have a save action like

```xml
  <xp:this.action>
     <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
  </xp:this.action>
```

or to use

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick"
    submit="true"
    refreshMode="complete"
    immediate="false"
    save="true">
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Or you can save the datasource like this:http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have added my code to the question.

Comment: Despite trying your helpful suggestions, I couldn't get the querySaveDocument event working so I solved the problem instead with CSJS.